# i.atcorr [GRASS] - has anyone used it and actually had success?

Tags: grass-gis, landsat-8, atmospheric-correction

I am trying to apply `i.atcorr` to a landsat mosaic with GRASS. These are my 6S parameters:

```
18
01 31 22.10 178.940 -17.263
1
1
0
0.115
-0.270
-1000
 116
```

Everytime I run it, it returns me a raster with only one value. I've changed the values, I've tried with dummy data, I've read the documentation several times. I have read literally all the questions here in stack gis about the use of `i.atcorr` with GRASS, and in their mailing list as well. There seems to be a lot of people that has the same output, this sort of blank raster, but there is not a clear solution to this.

Has anybody applied this algorithm successfully to Landsat 8 and, if so, any idea on I am possibility doing wrong?

**Edit:
GRASS GIS 7.4.4. on Windows 10.

Comment: The third number in the second line is the hour of the satellite pass-over. Is your image really at 22:10 ??

Comment: @Micha Thank you for your comment. I saw that value on the MTL file, where it says : 
   ` LANDSAT_SCENE_ID = "LC80740722014031LGN01"
    LANDSAT_PRODUCT_ID = LC08_L1TP_074072_20140131_20170426_01_T1"
    FILE_DATE = 2017-04-26T02:36:36Z
    DATA_TYPE = "L1TP"
    COLLECTION_CATEGORY = "T1"
    ELEVATION_SOURCE = "GLS2000"
    OUTPUT_FORMAT = "GEOTIFF"
    SPACECRAFT_ID = "LANDSAT_8"
    WRS_PATH = 74
    WRS_ROW = 72
    TARGET_WRS_PATH = 74
    TARGET_WRS_ROW = 72
    DATE_ACQUIRED = 2014-01-31
    SCENE_CENTER_TIME = "22:07:41.5744440Z"
    CORNER_UL_LAT_PRODUCT = -16.2983`

Comment: Therefore, I would assume that `Scene_center_time` is the time that the scene was recorded, according to https://landsat.usgs.gov/landsat-science-data-products-metadata

Comment: Please edit and add the GRASS GIS version + operating system to your question. We recently released some updates to i.atcorr

Comment: Fine. Just FYI - we just released https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/Release/7.6.0-News including a specific update to i.atcorr fixing some numerical instabilities among other improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to duplicate your process (GRASS 7.4.3 on Debian) and it seems to work as expected. Here are the commands I used after downloading and unzipping the tile you used:

```
# Import the bands to GRASS
for t in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11; do r.in.gdal input=LC08_L1TP_074072_20140131_20170426_01_T1_B${t}.TIF output=lc8_b${t} --o; done 

# TOA reflectance
i.landsat.toar -r input=lc8_b output=lc8_toar metfile=LC08_L1TP_074072_20140131_20170426_01_T1_MTL.txt sensor=oli8 --o

# Three different 6s_params files with different last line 
# 116,117,118 for blue, green, red bands
# Atmospheric correction
for b in 2 3 4; do i.atcorr input=lc8_toar${b} out=lc8_atcorr${b} param=6s_params${b}.txt --o; done
```

The results (below) are composite of bands 4,3,2 (RGB). It doesn't look so impressive, maybe the correction parameters need to be tweaked. But it's definitely working. 
Note the **-r flag** to `i.landsat.toar`

[image: Before correction]
[image: After]

Comment: In addition, you can try https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/i.colors.enhance.html

Comment: @Micha, I understood the problem. When performing i.atcorr I was putting the values directly on the prompt and that was what gave me the empty raster. After, I've created the .txt files with the parameters, used them as input and the i.atcorr performed well.

Comment: @markusN, I will definitely take a look into that! Thanks